# Running a PHP application on the Internet in Apache

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, deployment

I am trying to help a friend to set up a PHP Application on Ubuntu and Apache 9.0, they have a public IP to use but they are clueless on how to configure the application to make it visible on the internet using such IP.

I have tried to lookup online and here but I couldnt find anything clear/helpfull enough, so I wonder if you guys could provide me of some info on how to achieve this.

Their Apache version is 9.0 and their distro is Ubuntu Server 9.1

Comment: The most recent version of the Apache web server is 2.2.21 -- so I'm not sure where you are getting "9.0" from? A couple of basic questions -- is it correct to assume that they have been running Apache on their own local network and the "problem" is just one of knowing how to make it available to the web? Do they have a domain name associated with their public IP adress?

Comment: Hi Murray, I am out of the office right now, but will ask my friend and answer this tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Murray again =), yes i just asked my friend and they do have a domain name. Let me know if that's useful for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wherever you purchased your domain, you need to go into the DNS controls and set an "A" record pointing to that public IP address of yours.  It will take a little while to propagate, but to accept that you need to setup a virtual host.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

In your apache config (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf) Find these values and set them.

- Listen 80
- NameVirtualHost *:80

Then you will need to setup a virtual host. 
In the command line type these out and be mindful of "yourdomain", "your_main_site_folder" that you need to replace that with relevant items.

```
 cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Then edit your file

```
sudo nano yourdomain.com.conf
```

Now paste in this and edit it to your needs:

```
< VirtualHost *:80 >

DocumentRoot /var/www/your_main_site_folder

ServerName www.yourdomain.com  

< /VirtualHost >
```

Once you're done type Ctrl+O to save and Ctrl+X to exit the nano editor.

Then in the command line again type:

```
sudo a2ensite yourdomain.com.conf
```

Then reload apache, and you're done.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Comment: Wes, one question, do I need to set up a Nat Forwarding on the router as well, or just the steps you just told me?.

Comment: Those steps should do just fine.  Port 80 is usually open by default.  If you need 443, just pop that one open too.  Quick google search

Comment: Thanks, gonna give it a try man!

Answer (score 1):

The public IP end-point is  most likely connected to a router. 
You will need to create NAT port forwarding from so that all of the traffic coming to port 80 (or 443 if using SSL/TLS) would be forwarded to the computer running the Apache server.
Also, you will need to modify your firewall to allow these connections.

Comment: Thanks Uku gonna try this out